# Wordrpess Subdomains (Multi-Site) without Wildcard

Tags: multisite, subdomains

I've installed Wordpress Multisite using "Subdomains" method (instead of Subfolders). But I've found out, that my current hosting doesnt support WildCard subdomains.

I use this method to setup it manually: https://puvox.software/blog/setup-wordpress-subdomains-for-multi-site-manually/

however, it has a small problem - it redirects (instead of rewriting) all assets to root domain... does any fix exists there?

Comment: If the host doesn't allow wildcards then you can also use an add-on domain or a parked domain, and point that to public_html or wherever you have WP installed.  I would not mess around with .htaccess trying to solve this.

Comment: how `parked domain` or `addon domain` will work?  I dont hope any of them to work, because I want subdomains..

Comment: Point sub.example.com to the wp install folder for WP.